# Two ui widget styles conflicting

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, stylesheet

I am using a ui multiselect widget as well as a ui ipod style menu widget.

I do not get any errors but the style of one seems to override the style of the other.

Is there a way to isolate the individual style sheets for each widget?  I tried pre-pending my multiselect id to the all the ui classes in both the jquerui style sheet and the jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom style sheet but I just ran into more issues.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: inspecting the element in chrome usually makes it clear which style comes from which rule. Can you post some code and/or a link? THanks

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of CSS :( Use Chrome's F12 tools to find the source of each elements styles